# Tagging github from Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins

I have stored the Timestamp to a variable and I need to use same Variable to tag github from Jenkins Job.
More precisely "Tag To Push" in Git Publisher, what should be the entry?
Added in Execute Shell Command:

APP_BUILD_TAG=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M')

echo $APP_BUILD_TAG > releaseStamp

When I enter Tag to Push = $APP_BUILD_TAG, it gives me error as it can not recognize $APP_BUILD_TAG. Please suggest the best practise so that i can tag with our convention as YYYYMMDD_HHMM format

Answer (score 0):

It is expected Failure,Tag To Push in Git publisher plugin allows usage of environment variables. But the variable value you have created is a local variable and has the scope with in that execute shell and will not be passed to post build step.

How to fix this:

add below:

```
echo "TAG_TO_PUSH=${APP_BUILD_TAG}" > releaseStamp.txt
```

and then use a inject environment build/post build step and inject this file. This will export this variable to entire jenkins job. So that your Tag To Push will also be able to consume the variable value.

Now in the Tag to push section, use the value below:

```
${TAG_TO_PUSH}
```

Comment: Note that this requires the [EnvInject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject).

Comment: @ChristopherOrr Agreed +1

Answer (score 0):

The EnvInject plugin won't let you generate a tag programmatically.  To work around this I found it necessary to use the EnvInject plugin *twice* -- once at the beginning, to generate the property/tag as a file, and once after SCM checkout, to read the file.

Using your example:

1. Ensure you have the EnvInject plugin installed.
2. Edit your Jenkins configuration.  Under 'General', check 'Prepare an
   environment for the run' (this section will be executed at the
   beginning).
3. In the 'Script content' text field, type:`echo "APP_BUILD_TAG=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M')" > /path/to/stamp.txt`
4. Scroll down to 'Build Environment'.  Check 'Inject environment
   variables into the build process' (this section will be executed
   after SCM checkout).
5. In the 'Properties file path' text field, type: `/path/to/stamp.txt`
6. Scroll to Post-build actions, check the Git Publisher plugin, add a
   tag.  In the 'Tag to push' text field, type: `${APP_BUILD_TAG}`

(Whether or not this is best-practice is anyone's guess; it seems like there should be an easier way, but this is the only way I could get it to work.)